# CTI Logout User

Tags: cti, force

We use CTI (with adapter).  The adapter is configured to logout users when no activity for 30 minutes (management doesn't want to change this setting)

The issue we're running into is some users shutdown their pc or close their browser withoug logging out of the CTI session.   The problem is the CTI connector thinks the user is still logged in and send calls to the user.  Since no one answers the call, prospective leads hangup and we potentially lose the lead

Is there a way to check if user closed the browser or shutdown computer and then if so, logout out the user from CTI?

Comment: Train the users, for starters. That aside, maybe you should get a better adapter/provider. The one we use logs out in a fraction of a second when the user closes the browser.

Comment: @sfdcfox too funny :-).  In all seriousness we have 1,000 reps and you might understand some forget to logout or just don't follow instructions.  Also, management doesn't want to change the settings of when to log users out because maybe a rep stepped away for a few minutes or is working in another tab .  Its seems the only way to this would be write an app the checks when computer is turned off (an event) and check if browser is open and if so send "event" to connector to logout user.